# How to configure jackson to use JaxbAnnotationIntrospector or JacksonAnnotationIntrospector depending on the field being serialized

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a wrapper class `WrapperClass`that encapsulates two objects: `ObjectOne` and `ObjectTwo`:

```
public class WrapperClass {
  ObjectOne objectOne;
  ObjectTwo objectTwo;
}
```

While serializing a `WrapperClass`instance, I want to use the `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` on `objectTwo` but not on `objectOne`. Is that possible?

I have looked into creating a custom annotation introspector that extends `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and overrides its `findSerializer()` method to pick JAXB's `findSerializer()` if the class type is `ObjectTwo.class`. Would that work?

Thank you.

Comment: So basically you want to exclude the objectOne? and only serialize the objectTwo?

Comment: No I don't want to exclude objectOne. I would like to serialize both objects but use different annotator introspectors for each object. I actually have gotten a response after asking fasterxml-databind github and was told that this is currently not formally supported. One idea would be to create a custom annotation introspector that delegates to either Jackson/Jaxb introspectors, there is a challenge there however in knowing which field/class/constructor gets delegated. I plan on taking a look at it more once I have more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my other comment. What I am trying to achieve is not currently formally supported by the Jackson lib. A customized AnnotationIntrospectorPair that properly delegates the introspection is an idea to how to go about this. I will look into this more in the future.